# Change Android CheckBox box's color programmatically (support library)?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-support-library

I'm trying to change the checkbox box's color programmatically to a different color than the theme's default. The problem is I was doing something like this:

```
checkbox.setSupportButtonTintList(ColorStateList);
```

It works but it seems, according its class documentation, this method has been restricted to be used only by classes from the same package (com.android.support). This is the warning I got from Android Studio:

```
AppCompatCheckBox.setSupportButtonTintList can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)
```

Is there a standard/correct way of doing this for all API levels?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally, found the answer here from one of the Google guys: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202235. I was right about not using:

```
checkbox.setSupportButtonTintList(ColorStateList);
```

It seems is a private API. Instead, you have to use:

```
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkbox, colorStateList);
```

Comment: Thanks! Also a useful tip: to create a ColorStateList programmatically you can use `ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_checkbox_selector)`

Answer (score 3):

Based on *rylexr* answer, you can specify the color in the following way:

```
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkboxView, ColorStateList
                        .valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chxAll.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#CC0000")));
```

chxAll is a object of   `android.widget.CheckBox`

replace the hexacolor code for desigred color